# Does presence of "|" [Bitwise Or] in query PARAM value have impact on performance Java Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Recently I encountered a strange issue where I had a table called person which has columns personid, name, age, username, ...

There are around 200 entries for username which as '|' in value.
i.e. for ex :

```
1] abc | def  
2] mno | pqr
```

and so on.

I Have return an Spring Boot based Rest API which deletes person based on username but I am observing that the API takes more than expected time when we try to delete person whose username value has "|" in it.
i.e. time taken to delete 10 records for username with "|" is app 10 mins but the usernames without "|" values takes process transaction with in 4 min.

I tried to google a lot to  find the impact of it but could not find any corresponding proof on it causing performance issue. Hence I am reaching out here .

Query used:

```
select * from person where username = trim (:name)
```

API Details:

Takes List of Usernames to be deleted or inactivated as input and have some set of basic validation before performing delete.

Comment: 10 records 10 minutes? What does it do? Have you checked the generated SQL?

Comment: Hi @SimonMartinelli, did check SQL following are 3 queries run in this case : 1] select * from person where name = trim('abc | def') .                 2] select * from person_cutomer_referer where person id = 'zcv1234' [ the value fetched from prior query.    3] select * from person_assitants where person id = 'zcv1234'

Comment: 4 minutes to delete entries without `|` seems already quite long. Maybe there is more than the pipe character that cause performance issue

Comment: I assume that you simply have a n+1 select problem. How many SQL statements are executed? To delete 10 records one SQL statement would be enough

Comment: @jhamon yes I do agree with you but there are a quite a bit of validations been done before deleting person So the average time of API is evaluated to 40-50 secs with all our earlier data but when we data which has bitwise or in value seems crossing our average time estimation

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes you rightly pointed we have n+1 problem as our ORM framework as bean customized over hibernate  in such a way that this exists through out application . but do you think Bitwise OR has anything to do with this as I tried with lot of data steps and end suspect the data with Bitwise Or is causing issue.

Comment: No I can't imagine that this is a problem

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Okay let me revisit code and think other possible perspectives , Thank you very much for the input it gives me a glance that I am missing something else.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with Hibernate or the Java part at all. The problem is with the database query. You probably don't have an index on `username` and also there's no reason to do the trimming in the query and not before the query.